# Java and mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I was just trying to connect my page to mysql database through the following script.

---

```
//  import java.sql.*;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc::mysql:://localhost::3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd"); 
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    String sqlquery="INSERT INTO `schooldatabase`.`test` (`name`) VALUES ('anyname');";
    con.commit();

}

catch(SQLException e){

}
```

However the following error meassage pops up.

---

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /final.jsp at line 20


18:     
19:     try {
20:         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
21:         Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc::mysql:://localhost::3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd");  
22:         Statement st=con.createStatement();
23:         String sqlquery="INSERT INTO `schooldatabase`.`test` (`name`) VALUES ('anyname');";


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

---

Is my driver name right for the mysql database ?? Kindly guide me through connecting java to a database.

Comment: Do you have a mysql driver in your classpath?

Comment: U have not included the driver for connecting to mysql database.

Comment: No.. I do not have mysql driver in my classpath..

Comment: @Abhinav : How can i include the driver ??

Comment: You can download driver from here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and add it to you lib folder.

Comment: add the mysql.jar to your WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: `line 20` is `Class.forName...` means you are missing jar file that needs to be included

Comment: You are using more colons:- "jdbc::mysql:://localhost::3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd"; try this:- "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd";

Comment: There should be the root cause logged somewhere. Find it and show us.

Comment: @user1262062 did you solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the JDBC URL has couple of additional colons

```
jdbc::mysql:://localhost::3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd"
```

try this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost::3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd"
```

Also as people have pointed out here, please also include the driver jar file. Simply put the jar in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application.

Comment: please give complete stack trace. Make sure there are no compilation errors on your page.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in this Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Surprise to see answers without knowing the root cause

Answer (score 1):

you have include the mysql jar file in java lib directory

and

you have to set the class path

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schooldatabase","root","passwd");
```

Comment: Please explain as i am very new to jdbc and such stuffs..'

Comment: download jar file and copy that into java jdk lib folder and include that path in environment variables

Comment: How to set that path in the environment variable ??

Answer (score 1):

line 20 is loading the driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, and it is not finding it.
kindly include **mysql-connector-java-5.XXX.jar** in class path.

link to download it http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

have a look at following example
http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/connect-jsp-mysql.shtml

Comment: check the added example,have you added it WEB-INF/lib? can you show complete JSP

Comment: How can i put the connector file in WEB-INF/lib. There is no lib folder inside WEB-INF.

Comment: create one folder lib and put it there o r in Eclipse go to project properties and in JAVA Build path, go to libraries tab and add JAR.